# the web page changes the style when I resize the size of my window.Can i make it look the same for any size of the window

Tags: html, css

```css
<style>html {
  background-color: snow;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  font-size: 60;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: "algerian";
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  padding: 100;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  height: 250;
  padding-bottom: 700;
}

#intro {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 100;
  padding-top: 50;
  font-family: "timesnewroman";
  font-size: 30;
}

#ii {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 40;
  background-width: 1500;
  color: floralwhite;
  padding-left: 500;
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>

<header>MY PROFILE</header>


<div>insert image</div>

<body>


  <section>

    <p id="ii"><b>PERSONAL DETAILS</b></p>

  </section>

  <section id="intro">

    <p>
      <B><br><br>Name &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; :</B> [name of the person] </p>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Web page created changes the looks or style when i resize the size of the window. Can I make the alignment of web page stay the same?

Eg: When the window is in full screen the alignment of left and right sides are perfect .But when I make the size of the window smaller. The content in the left remains but the content on the right moves to the bottom after the whole left content is over

I have tried changing the viewport in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2FAt.jpg) the details of name moved down after I made window smaller.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onresize="resize()">
<p id="size"></p>
<script>
function resize() 
{
  var width = window.outerWidth;
  var height = window.outerHeight;
  var sizes = "Window size: width=" + width + ", height=" + height;
  document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = sizes;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use the window.outerWidth and height to position the text/elements...
If you need any more help, would you mind posting the code so I could take a look?
Thanks :)